# Firebase functions - new functions added are not being allowed to run

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Weird case. I've got a number of firebase cloud functions. I've added a new one today. It deploys fine, but doesn't run. It's not possible to even call it for some reason. To isolate potential code errors in the new function, I've dropped another working function into this new one and it doesn't run either. If I replace the contents of an existing function by the new one's contents, then it runs. It's as if Firebase had silently introduced a limit on having new functions or just stopped running any new ones. I've tried it on two different instances so far and the issue persists.

To replicate, take an existing project with some functions. Duplicate one of the functions - say a simple https request and give it a new name. The new function will be identical to the old one, but it won't run with the browser saying `"Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /newFunction from this server."`

It's quite a weird behaviour especially as it's possible to get a new function to run only by replacing an older function with the contents of the new one and calling the older function. Then it runs fine and without any complaints from the server.

Anyone know what might be causing this and how to fix this strange behaviour?

Comment: Please contact Firebase support directly for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @Doug Are you seeing a similar issue when adding a new function to an existing project? 
Any idea how long it usually takes the support to respond?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently, Firebase introduced a change as of January 15, 2020 that HTTP functions require authentication by default.

You have to specify whether a function allows unauthenticated invocation at or after deployment. This can be done in the dashboard of all the functions or via console.

It would be good if the error message they provide explained all of that - would have saved me many hours of trouble-shooting.